# Gun shoots even if gun isnt picked up Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My gun code is linked to the gun itself, however even when I'm not holding the gun (aka it's not picked up yet) the gun still shoots and fires at where I'm looking, I will give the code and I'm thinking of something like 'if is child then shoot'.

Here is the code in question, if you need the full code I'd be happy to oblige.

```
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public float fireRate = 15f;
public float Impact = 40f;


public Camera fpsCam;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public GameObject impactEffect;

private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
    {
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }

}

void Shoot()
{
```

Comment: You could just disable the script and then on pickup enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public float fireRate = 15f;
public float Impact = 40f;


public Camera fpsCam;
public bool pickedUp = false;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public GameObject impactEffect;

private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire && pickedUp)
    {
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }

}
```

When the gun is picked up, set the `pickedUp` boolean to true and false when it is dropped.

Comment: so far looks like its working, will 100% confirm when i fix a few errors that let me play test.

Comment: the base of it is working, im just trying to figure out a way to make two of my scripts interact to make it a lot smoother, basically just trying to make it so that when picked up it fires, if i check the boxes off or on myself in debug it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public float damage = 10f;
public float range = 100f;
public float fireRate = 15f;
public float Impact = 40f;

public Camera fpsCam;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public GameObject impactEffect;

private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire && parent != null)
    {
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }

}
```